# Mixing Classic ASP with MVC - Issues with same paths

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp-classic, routes

We are slowly trying to migrate away from our classic asp pages to mvc views but I have come across an issue which I am struggling to figure out!

We want to keep the same url structure so I had created a controller/action to point to the same url, however this is being ignored and the asp file is always taking priority.

Example:

I have the folder structure: **adults\policies\index.asp**
and an MVC controller called **Adults** with an action called **Policies**

When I browse to the url: **..co.uk\adults\policies**

I expect the browser to go to my new controller action method but it is always going to the classic asp file location instead.

If I try to rename index.asp to something else I'll get a permissions error (so it is still attempting to use the classic asp path rather than the MVC controller action all the time).

I've spent hours trying to play around with routing but I can't seem to get it working. It's important that we keep the same url structure so I can't give my controller / action an alternative name to solve it.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks!

Edit:

I've sort of been able to get this to work using a rewrite module with some regex to then append the word "/index" on the end which then makes it go to the mvc view.

I don't know what pattern to use to ignore urls with an extension on the end though i.e. .asp / .jpeg etc. because the url is turning into /adults/policies/test.asp/index

So far I have included this pattern:

/?([^:/\s]+)((/\w+)*/)([\w-.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w-]+)?$

Taken from here: http://www.regextester.com/20

Can anyone help so that this rewrite module won't kick in when there is a url with a .* on the end?

Comment: Is your applicationPool running Integrated Mode or Classic Mode??

Comment: Sounds like it is following the default route like it should be. You can view the routes that have been set up by viewing your App_Start\RouteConfig.cs file. I'm not sure if it is possible to mix classic asp with the MVC framework. You could try defining routes for all of your old asp pages and then inside the action being routed to you would load that asp page. I would start by trying to call `return View("classic/page.asp");` and go from there. Depending on how those pages are set up though, I'm positive this won't work.

Comment: Instead of using MVC's routing, have you tried using the IIS url rewrite module - http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: @Andrew Bonsall mixing asp with mvc is working fine, the only issue is when I try to call an action which also has as asp file in the same file path. I don't want to load the asp page but the mvc view instead. I think based on what you wrote you're telling me the other way round.

Comment: @John there are already a few rewrite modules in place. I'm going to try removing these to see if they are causing the issue.

Hopefully someone has come across this issue before. I'm thinking I have to add something to the routeconfig file to make it work. 

I tried the setting `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;` which worked but then all of my asp files will fail to load (404 error). 

Strangely if I call the url: **\adults\policies\index** it then works fine but I don't want the word "index" to be in the url.

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood what you were asking. Have you tried passing the path to the new view file `return View("new/view.cshtml");`. You could also remove the asp page from the server. I'm not sure how IIS determines which request to pass to the MVC handler and when to load static content (like a js file or an image) but most open source MVC solutions usually use a rewrite rule that says if the requested file exists in my webroot then serve that else pass to my MVC handler.

Comment: If I delete the file I get a permissions error because the folder still exists (there are other files in there that I still want to use). There would be no point in writing return view.... because the action doesn't get hit. I got this working through a hacky way using urlrewrite which appends "/index" to the url in the background but not in the browser. This obviously isn't an ideal solution because it's not generic enough at the moment to work in all scenarios. I hoping there was some sort of setting I could apply to MVC routing / url rewrite to make it work properly.

Answer (score 1):

according to this articel https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/mixing-web-forms-and-asp.net-mvc/ you need to make sure that your MVC routing has a route defined for this controller/action.

Therefore make sure that you don't have a rule like this defined in your `RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)` function inside of your RouteConfig.cs file that will ignore the route.

```
//Do not route requests for /adults/policies/any/additional/path
routes.IgnoreRoute("adults/policies/");
//Do not route for adults/policies/any/additional/path?withquerystring=true
routes.IgnoreRoute("adults/policies/{*pathInfo}");
```

also, make sure you have somthing like this in your. `RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)` function inside of your RouteConfig.cs file

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Adult Policies",
    "adults\policies\index.asp"
    new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction"}
);
```

Unfortunately it will be very difficult if not impossible to create a route that will catch all of the .asp pages that you want to route in this way since, as you mentioned in your comments, there are other asp files in that folder that you still want to serve up. This means that you are going to have to create a route like this every time you replace one of these pages, up until the point where you have replaced all of the pages, in which case a catch all for that controller is simple.

The other option is creating a very specific ignore rule for all of the current asp pages in that folder and removing them one by one as you convert them to actions. And of course having a very broad route defined that will catch all of the request to that folder.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm afraid you're right on the difficulty of doing this task since I have sub-files (asp files) that I still need the website to have access to. So I have decided to create rewrite modules for now on the specific pages that I am going to be updating i.e. `<rule name="policies redirection">
          <match url="adults/policies" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}/index" />
        </rule>`